# How to show product category description below list of products?

Tags: product

I was wondering how to make my category description visible at the product category page?

Because I´ve wrote much of content, but it doesen´t appear on the product category sites. I want it to be shown below the list of products.

Comment: So you want to display the category description to display at the bottom of the category list page?

Comment: @rob3000 exactly!

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

A much cleaner way without editing files.

Go to the corresponding category and navigate to the Design - Custom XML Updates tab, and add the below code - where "your_static_block" should be renamed to the name (Identifier) of the static block you want to display on the bottom.

```
<reference name="content">

<block type="cms/block" name="your_static_block" after="-">
    <action method="setBlockId"><id>your_static_block</id></action>
  </block>
</reference>
```

Then you can edit your content with a static block! The content is displayed below the product list in the category view. This way you can still use the category description for a little intro, and the remainder of the text can be placed below. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can copy `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/category/view.phtml` to `/app/design/frontend/{{YOUR_PACKAGE}}/{{YOUR_THEME}}/template/catalog/category/view.phtml` and move the following code snippet:

```
<?php if($_description=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
    <div class="category-description std">
        <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

under the following code snippet:

```
<?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look please

Solution 1:

Set product attribute for description field "Used in Product Listing" to "YES" and then you can get a description.

Solution 2:

In list.phtml under a foreach add :

```
$myDescription = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
    echo $myDescription->getDescription();
```

I recommend you to use a first solution to avoid redundant model load.